# How to validate the content of a DataGridCell, when the bound property is of type integer

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a simple `List<IntObject>` in my `ViewModel.cs`. The class `IntObject` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and a property `Value` which is of type int.
The list is used as the `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid`.

**My problem:** 
When I type a character in a cell a red border is displayed and I get a exception in my output window. That makes sense to me. 
My DataGridColumns are auto-generated, and it is not possible to generate them manually.

Is it possible to catch all exception the datagrid is throwing in a mvvm like way?

Comment: Tricky, because I think you'd need to set NotifyOnValidationError on every binding. That then raises a routed event when you get a type conversion error. You can handle that in a parent control/panel. You would have to override the column generation and add that to any bindings. Even without that complication the approach is kind of involved.

Comment: This occurs because WPF attempts to convert the string into an int to write it back to the ViewModel. The real problem is that your ViewModel doesn't know that it tried and failed, so it doesn't know the old value has been changed and that it's no longer valid.

The best way I've found to solve this is to wrap the int with a string property, keep track of the error in the ViewModel (using INotifyDataErrorInfo), and pass the value back to the int when it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the view model's responsibility to validate that the view or control sets one of its `int` properties to a valid `int` value. This validation should be performed in the view or in the control. You may use a `ValidationRule` or/and a `RowValidationErrorTemplate` to customize row validation feedback. Please refer to the following MSDN page for more information about this.

**How to: Implement Validation with the DataGrid Control:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-implement-validation-with-the-datagrid-control

If you are auto-generating the columns, you could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` to customize the generated columns. But you can't set an `int` source property to anything else than an `int` value.